# how to reverse CSS animation on second click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, function, animation, reverse

I have made the following menu icon CSS animation that triggers when i click on it. I want to make it animate in reverse when i click on it for the second time using jQuery.

```
#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 33px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 33px;
  animation: line 1.5s linear forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes line {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -15.5;
  }
}

#halfLineLeft {
  transform-origin: 1% 50%;
  animation: shrinkleft 1s linear forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

 #halfLineRight {
  transform-origin: 100% 1%;
  animation: shrinkleft 1s linear forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes shrinkleft {
  100% {
    transform: scale(0,1);
  }
}
svg {
  transform: translate(350px, 200px);
}
```

and this is the jQuery i have so far...

```
$("svg").click(
  function(){
     $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").css("animation-play-state", "running");
  }
 );
```

I cant seem to figure out how to make it animate in reverse when i click on the SVG icon the second time. I tried this code without any luck:

```
$("svg").click(
  function(){
     $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").css("animation-state", "running"),
     $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").css("animation-direction", "reverse");
  }
 );
```

Here is the codepen link with the live animation:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEORBJ

Comment: Maybe you could add a variable to store the number of clicks.  One first click run first animation, on second click run the other.

Comment: @Trialsman or just boolean that changes from true to false and back. And on every click it goes `whichAnimation = !whichAnimation`

Comment: have you considered toggling a class for this?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks Yes, Boolean is better than counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but adding reverse keyframes and toggling classes seems to work.

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/pythagoras1357/pen/zKBdwx)

```
#path1.active {
  animation: line 1.5s forwards;
}

#path1.inactive {
  stroke-dashoffset: -15.5;
  animation: unline 1s linear forwards;
}

#halfLineLeft.active {
  animation: shrinkleft 1s linear forwards;
}

#halfLineRight.active {
  animation: shrinkleft 1s linear forwards;
}

#halfLineLeft.inactive {
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  animation: unshrinkleft 1s linear forwards;
}

#halfLineRight.inactive {
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  animation: unshrinkleft 1s linear forwards;
}

#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 33px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 33px;
}

@keyframes line {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -15.5;
  }
}

@keyframes unline {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 33px;
  }
}

@keyframes shrinkleft {
  100% {
    transform: scale(0, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes unshrinkleft {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

#halfLineLeft {
  transform-origin: 1% 50%;
}

#halfLineRight {
  transform-origin: 100% 1%;
}

svg {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px);
}

$("svg").click(
  function() {
    $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").toggleClass("active");

    if (!$("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").hasClass("active")) {

      $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").addClass("inactive");

    } else {
      $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").removeClass("inactive");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. I will have to use it since i can't figure out another way but what i was really looking for is for a way to not rewrite the opposite animation and toggle the class, but to add the css property "animation-direction: reverse" on the second clicking of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class and then remove it. Check this

```
$("svg").on('click',function(){
    if($("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").hasClass('forward')){
        $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").css("animation-direction", "reverse").removeClass('forward');
    }else{
     $("#path1, #halfLineLeft, #halfLineRight").css("animation-play-state", "running").addClass('forward');
    }  

  });
```

Comment: I tried this code but it just jumps to the initial frame of the animation without the reverse animation being viewed, plus after returning to the initial frame it doesn't respond to any more clicking.