# CSS animation-direction: reverse allpied with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code that makes my `div` rotate forward every time I press "right" arrow - this works fine, but I've also added an instruction to make `div` rotate backwards every time I press "left" arrow - that's the part not working.

I'am trying to do that by changing `animation-direction` property to "reverse" using jQuery `.css()` method

here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      $(".box").css({
        "animation-direction": "normal",
        "animation-play-state": "running"
      })

    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      $(".box").css({
        "animation-direction": "reverse",
        "animation-play-state": "running"
      })
    }
  });

  $(document).keyup(function() {
    $(".box").css("animation-play-state", "paused")
  });

});
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

@keyframes infinite-spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.box {
  animation-name: infinite-spinning;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? because it seems like your code is working like it should, in your code snippet as well as in this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21kkb9pj/)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity For me the div is not rotating backwards when I press "left" arrow.

Comment: I just tested it again in Chrome and FF and it works fine, IE11 plays it forward in both cases!

Comment: oh, You re right, it's just a matter of browser. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating two separated keyframes fixes the direction of rotation problem, there's a problem when you click the opposite arrow to get the `.box` moving in the other direction there'll be kind of snapping, depending on how close to **`90`** or **`270`** degrees the last rotation angle is, that is because both the forward and backward movement starts from a fixed step, angle **`0`** forward, or **`360`** backward, so it jumps to start from there. if this is not a problem then this is working great.

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/p5uh1t9f/) - Chrome, Firefox, IE10+

---

To fix the above glitching and get accurate rotation, you can drop the usage of keyframes totally and no need for the `keyup` event listener either, like below:

**METHOD 1**

Use `transform` [ [CSS3 animations vs transitions](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/css3_animations_vs_transitions.htm) ] to control the rotation angle,like below:

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9721aL7/5/) - Chrome, Firefox, IE9+

```js
var rot8 = 0,
  bx = $('.box');

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rot8 += 3;
    bx.css({ 'transform' : 'rotate(' +rot8+ 'deg)' });
  } 
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    rot8 -= 3;
    bx.css({ 'transform' : 'rotate(' +rot8+ 'deg)' });
  }
  
});
```

```css
.box { display: inline-block; border: 2px solid black; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"><h1>TEST</h1></div>
```

**METHOD 2**

Using GSAP [ [GreenSock Animation Platform](https://greensock.com/) ]

[**jsFiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/8qm6a6cw/7/) - Chrome, Firefox, IE9+ <sup>works on IE8 too but it needs CSS tweakig concerning box boundaries</sup>

```js
var bx = $('.box');

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
    TweenMax.to( bx, 0.1, { rotation: '+=5' });
    }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    TweenMax.to( bx, 0.1, { rotation: '-=5' });
  }
});
```

```css
.box { display: inline-block; border: 2px solid black; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"><h1>TEST</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to write separate `keyframes` and work with classes. See [here](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-with-jquery-reverse-animation/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537494/how-to-reverse-css-animation-on-second-click-with-jquery).